# Loop not ending when if statement condition fails - SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell, loop

In SP2010, I'm trying to move files from one library to another using Powershell. The condition for file move is that the files should be greater than 3 years/1095 days from the date of creation.

I'm using the below script to first copy the files from source to destination and then delete the source file.

This works perfectly for files which passes the condition that is for files which are greater than 1095 days, the file gets copied to destination and then gets deleted in source.

But when the loop faces the 1st file which doesn't pass the condition, the loop starts repeating infinitely and doesn't move to the next document. What is that I'm missing?

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-Content -path "C:\temp\MovedFiles.csv"
$OuputFile = "C:\temp\MovedFiles.csv" 
#Custom Function to Copy Files from Source Folder to Target
Function Copy-Files($SourceFolder, $TargetFolder)
{
write-host "Copying Files from:$($SourceFolder.URL) to $($TargetFolder.URL)"
#Get Each File from the Source
$SourceFilesColl = $SourceFolder.Files
write-host "Collection count:" $SourceFilesColl.Count
#Iterate through each item from the source
for($i = 0; $i -lt $SourceFilesColl.Count)
{
 $SourceFile=$SourceFilesColl[$i]
 write-host "Source File:" $SourceFile
 $today = get-date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
 $Created= $SourceFile.TimeCreated
 $TS = New-Timespan -start $Created -End $today
 $datedifference = $ts.days

 if($datedifference -gt 1095)
 {
    #Copy File from the Source
 Write-host "Coping File:"$SourceFile.Name
 $NewFile = $TargetFolder.Files.Add($SourceFile.Name, $SourceFile.OpenBinary(),$True)
  Foreach($Field in $SourceFile.Item.Fields)
 {
    If(!$Field.ReadOnlyField)
    {
        if($NewFile.Item.Fields.ContainsField($Field.InternalName))
        {
            $NewFile.Item[$Field.InternalName] = $SourceFile.Item[$Field.InternalName]
        }
    }
}

 #Update
$NewFile.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
Write-host "Copied File:"$SourceFile.Name
$movedfiles= Add-Content -Path C:\temp\MovedFiles.csv -Value "$($SourceFile.Name.ToString())"

 $SourceFile.Delete()
 Write-host "Deleted File from source:"$SourceFile.Name 
 } 
 else
{
 write-host "This file not moved:" $SourceFile.Name
}
} 
}
#Variables for Processing
$WebURL="SiteURL"
$SourceLibrary ="SourceLibrary"  
$TargetLibrary = "TargetLibrary"

#Get Objects
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$SourceFolder = $Web.GetFolder($SourceLibrary)
$TargetFolder = $Web.GetFolder($TargetLibrary)

#Call the Function to Copy All Files
Copy-Files $SourceFolder $TargetFolder

$tempCSV = Import-Csv C:\temp\MovedFiles.csv -Header "File" | select -skip 0
$tempCSV | Export-CSV C:\temp\MovedFiles.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: can you try ++$i in the else condition? so that $i is value change

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP great. that worked :)

Comment: i added that part as answer if you marked it that will be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like their is no increment for the $i variable in the Else condition. so thats why it stuck on the same item all the item.

Can you put this in `else` condition.

```
++$i
```